# JAVA CSV file to Map<String, List<Double>>

Tags: java, csv, dictionary

I am asked to create a word vector space from a csv file. So I need to extract words and their vectors(the size is 57) to a dictionary for being able to reuse it for my futur operations.
My csv format is giving me a lot of problems because it's basically a text with key and doubles all separated by spaces and i wasn't able to separate correctly string and double parts until now.

So do you have any idea how to parse this file into a dictionary which contains (key, vector) type of entries.

Thanks a lot.

Here is a demonstration of csv file:

```
key1 4.0966564 7.963437 -2.1844673 1.9319566 -0.04495791 2.454401 3.1006012 -0.3813638 1.567303 -2.2067556 3.44506744 -4.382278 4.1457844 2.342756 -2.7707205 3.5015 2.5717492 -2.6846366...

key2 -3.968007 0.86151505 0.06163538 1.918614 0.34340435 -1.5178788 1.3857365 0.230331 0.7025755 -2.6575062 -0.7426953 3.1636698 2.8441591 0.4522623 3.3907628 2.425691 -1.2052362....
```

.
.
.

Comment: `line.split(" ");` should give you all the needed values (the string being the first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This data structure is called a multi-map: a key can have multiple values.

You can find examples in libraries.

If you'd rather not have the dependency, and wish to write your own, it might look like this:

```
public class MultiMap {
    private Map<String, List<Double>> multi = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(String key, Double newValue) {
        if (newValue != null) {
            List<Double> values = (this.multi.containsKey(key) ? this.multi.get(key) : new ArrayList<>());
            values.add(newValue);
            this.multi.put(key, values);
        }
    }
}
```

It's possible to use generics, but I'm too lazy to bother right now.  This example is correct for your narrow use case.

Split each line into tokens by splitting at regex `"\\s+"`.  The first value is the key; iterate over all the others to add them to the multi-map.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it out. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
String line = "key1 4.0966564 7.963437";
String[] parts = line.split(" ");
String key = parts[0];
ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>();
for(int i =1; i < parts.length; i++){
  String doubleAsString = parts[i];
  values.add(Double.valueOf(doubleAsString));
}
```

And then add this elements to your map.